# Trace of squared non-square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

In reading a paper I came across [this expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWp0S.png) which I don't quite understand:
$$
    \frac{\lambda_1}{2N}\operatorname{tr}\left((\mathbf{H}^M\mathbf{H}^M)^T\right)
$$
For context, $\lambda_1$ and $N$ are scalars and $\mathbf{H}^M$ ($H$ henceforth) is a $MxN$ matrix.

The paper claims that this value is related to the variance of the column vectors which make up H, but either there is a typo or (quite likely) a linear algebra concept I don't know. The reason I am confused is that trace requires square input, and if H were to be made square then the transpose would have to apply to one of the two $H$s, not both after multiplying them (which itself doesn't make sense to me because only a square matrix can be multiplied by itself in the first place).

The paper is [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/219b/7b157f2a559ecdffe21c2a0edf5285931298.pdf), the mentioned expression is at the bottom of the third page in equation (5).

Comment: Could it be $\mathbf{H}^M (\mathbf{H}^M)^T$ instead?  That would be square for any matrix $\mathbf{H}^M$.

Comment: That is what I had been thinking, but assuming that I haven't been able to figure out what the relationship to the variance of the column vectors would be. At that point it becomes a stats question more than a linalg one. If that were a typo then the trace results in the sum of the element-wise square of H, which to me seems more correlated to magnitude of values than variance.

Comment: Good point, added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a typo. In the paper that you have linked, the equation(12) on page(4) rewrites

$$
arg.min .J = ... -\frac{\lambda_1}{2}\Bigl(tr\bigl(\frac{1}{N}H^M(H^M)^T\bigr)+\alpha tr(\Sigma_B-\Sigma_W)\Bigr) + ...
$$

with the transpose correctly placed.